# Подскажите легкий скрипт аудиоплеера

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите скрипт аудиоплеера, который можно было бы использовать с минимальными изменениями в разметке - например, задать соответствующие классы уже существующим элементам, чтобы не создавалась автоматически куча элементов. Возможности нужны минимальные: прокрутка при помощи ползунка, текущее время, общее время, старт/пауза и, в общем, все.

Comment: Думаю, Вам поможет эта [ссылка](http://easy-code.ru/lesson/html5-jquery-web-audio-player).

Comment: я не понял вам нужна в общем все ?или же  минимальные возможности? все таки определитесь

Comment: @Избыток сусликов, `в общем, все` = `end;`.

Answer (score 0):

Все что вам надо тут есть

> прокрутка при помощи ползунка текущее время, общее время, старт/пауза
>   .

С комментариями

Скрипт поддерживает самые старые браузеры

```js
var AudioPlayer = function(options) {
  
  this.options = options || {};

  // context for addEventListener
  var self = this;
  

  // HTML MEDIA ELEMENT (AUDIO TAG)

  // get audio-file element from DOM
  this.audioFile = document.getElementById('audio-file') || null;
  
  this.audioPreload = 'auto' || this.options.audioPreload;
  
  this.audioSource = 'http://audio.ngfiles.com/152000/152047_ParagonX9___Chaoz_Impact.mp3' || this.options.audioSource;
    
  this.audioType = 'audio/mp3' || this.options.audioType;
 
  // check where audio tag exists
  if (this.audioFile) {
    
    // set attributes on audio tag
    this.audioFile.setAttribute('preload', this.audioPreload);
    this.audioFile.setAttribute('itemprop', 'audio');
    
    // create source tag
    var sourceTag = document.createElement('source');
    
    // add source tag inside of audio tag
    this.audioFile.appendChild(sourceTag);
    
    // set attributes on source tag
    sourceTag.setAttribute('src', this.audioSource);
    sourceTag.setAttribute('type', this.audioType);

    // add event
    this.audioFile.ontimeupdate = function() {

      self.updateTime();
    
    };

    // add event
    this.audioFile.ondurationchange = function() {

      self.displayAudioDuration();

    };

  } else {
    
    console.log('error - no audio tag with id audio-file present in html');
    
  }

  // AUDIO PLAYER
  
  // get audio-player element from DOM
  this.audioPlayerContainer = document.getElementById('audio-player') || null;
    
  // check audio file present then provide fallback to default browser audio player
  if (this.audioFile && !this.audioPlayerContainer) {
    
    var controlsAttribute = document.createAttribute('controls');
    
    this.audioFile.setAttributeNode(controlsAttribute);
    
    // check audio file present then include audio player
  } else if (this.audioFile && this.audioPlayerContainer) {
    
      // PLAY / PAUSE
      
      // create a flag
      this.playPauseBtnInclude =  (this.options.playPauseBtn === false) ? false : true;

      // check value to determine whether to include
      if (this.playPauseBtnInclude) {

        // create box
        var playPauseBtnBox = document.createElement('div');
        playPauseBtnBox.setAttribute('class', 'box-playpause');
        
        // create audio start time element
        var playPauseBtnEl = document.createElement('div');
        playPauseBtnEl.setAttribute('id', 'play-pause-btn');
        playPauseBtnEl.innerHTML = '&#x25b6';

        // add element to box
        playPauseBtnBox.appendChild(playPauseBtnEl);

        // set element to use for play/pause button used in methods
        this.playPauseBtn = playPauseBtnEl;
        
        // add box that in includes play/pause button element to audio player
        this.audioPlayerContainer.appendChild(playPauseBtnBox);
        
        // add event
        
        this.playPauseBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {

          self.playPauseAudio();
        
        }, false);

      }
      // STOP
    
      // create a flag
      this.stopBtnInclude =  (this.options.stopBtn === false) ? false : true;
    
      // check value to determine whether to include
      if (this.stopBtnInclude) {

        // create box
        var stopBtnBox = document.createElement('div');
        stopBtnBox.setAttribute('class', 'box-stopbtn');
        
        // create audio start time element
        var stopBtnEl = document.createElement('div');
        stopBtnEl.setAttribute('id', 'stop-btn');

        // add element to box
        stopBtnBox.appendChild(stopBtnEl);

        // set element to use for play/pause button used in methods
        this.stopBtn = stopBtnEl;
        
        // add box that in includes play/pause button element to audio player
        this.audioPlayerContainer.appendChild(stopBtnBox);
        
        // add event
        this.stopBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {

          self.stopAudio();

        }, false);

      }
      // AUDIO START TIME
    
      // create a flag
      this.audioFileStartInclude = (this.options.audioFileStart === false) ? false : true;
  
      // check value to determine whether to include
      if (this.audioFileStartInclude) {

        // create box
        var audioFileStartBox = document.createElement('div');
        audioFileStartBox.setAttribute('class', 'box-audiofilestart');
        
        // create audio start time element
        var audioFileStartEl = document.createElement('div');
        audioFileStartEl.setAttribute('id', 'audio-file-start');
        audioFileStartEl.innerHTML = '0:00';

        // add element to box
        audioFileStartBox.appendChild(audioFileStartEl);

        // set element to use for audio file start time used in methods
        this.audioFileStart = audioFileStartEl;
        
        // add box that in includes audio start time element to audio player
        this.audioPlayerContainer.appendChild(audioFileStartBox);

      }
      // PROGRESS BAR
    
      // create a flag
      this.progressBarInclude = (this.options.progressBar === false) ? false : true;
    
       // check value to determine whether to include
      if (this.progressBarInclude) {

        // create box
        var progressBarBox = document.createElement('div');
        progressBarBox.setAttribute('class', 'box-progressbar');
        
        // create progress bar container
        var progressBarContainerEl = document.createElement('div');
        progressBarContainerEl.setAttribute('id', 'audio-progress-container');
        
        // create progress bar
        var progressBarEl = document.createElement('div');
        progressBarEl.setAttribute('id', 'audio-progress-bar');
        
        // add bar element to container element
        progressBarContainerEl.appendChild(progressBarEl);
        
        // add container element (including bar element) to box
        progressBarBox.appendChild(progressBarContainerEl);
       
        // set element used in methods
        this.audioProgressContainer = progressBarContainerEl;
        
        // set element used in methods
        this.audioProgressBar = progressBarEl;
        
        // add box that in includes progress container and bar to audio player
        this.audioPlayerContainer.appendChild(progressBarBox);

        // add event
        this.audioProgressContainer.addEventListener('click', function() {

          self.setAudioPosition(this,event);

        }, false);

      }

      // AUDIO DURATION (total time)

      // create a flag
      this.audioFileEndInclude = (this.options.audioFileEnd === false) ? false : true;
    
       // check value to determine whether to include
      if (this.audioFileEndInclude) {

        // create box
        var audioFileEndBox = document.createElement('div');
        audioFileEndBox.setAttribute('class', 'box-audiofileend');
        
        // create audio end time element
        var audioFileEndEl = document.createElement('div');
        audioFileEndEl.setAttribute('id', 'audio-file-end');
        audioFileEndEl.innerHTML = '0:00';

        // add element to box
        audioFileEndBox.appendChild(audioFileEndEl);

        // set element to use for audio file end time used in methods
        this.audioFileEnd = audioFileEndEl;
        
        // add box that in includes audio end time element to audio player
        this.audioPlayerContainer.appendChild(audioFileEndBox);

      }
 
      // VOLUME ICON AND BAR
    
      // create flags
      this.volumeIconInclude = (this.options.volumeIcon === false) ? false : true;
      this.volumeBarInclude = (this.options.volumeBar === false) ? false : true;
    
      // check values to determine whether to include
      if (this.volumeIconInclude && this.volumeBarInclude) {
        
        // create box
        var volumeIconBox = document.createElement('div');
        volumeIconBox.setAttribute('class', 'box-volumeicon');
        
        // create volume element
        var volumeIconContainerEl = document.createElement('div');
        volumeIconContainerEl.setAttribute('id', 'volume-icon-container');
        
        // create volume icon element
        var volumeIconEl = document.createElement('div');
        volumeIconEl.setAttribute('id', 'volume-icon');
        
        // create soundwave elements
        var volumeSoundwaveOne = document.createElement('span');
        volumeSoundwaveOne.innerHTML = ')';
        
        var volumeSoundwaveTwo = document.createElement('span');
        volumeSoundwaveTwo.innerHTML = ')';
        
        var volumeSoundwaveThree = document.createElement('span');
        volumeSoundwaveThree.innerHTML = ')';
        
        // add soundwaves to volume icon element
        volumeIconEl.appendChild(volumeSoundwaveOne);
        volumeIconEl.appendChild(volumeSoundwaveTwo);
        volumeIconEl.appendChild(volumeSoundwaveThree);
        
        // add volume-icon to volume icon container
        volumeIconContainerEl.appendChild(volumeIconEl);
        
        // add volume icon container to box
        volumeIconBox.appendChild(volumeIconContainerEl);
        
        // set element to use for volume icon
        this.audioVolume = volumeIconContainerEl;
        
        // add box audio player
        this.audioPlayerContainer.appendChild(volumeIconBox);
        
        // create box
        var volumeLevelBox = document.createElement('div');
        volumeLevelBox.setAttribute('class', 'box-volumelevel');
        
        // create volume level container
        var volumeLevelContainerEl = document.createElement('div');
        volumeLevelContainerEl.setAttribute('id', 'volume-level-container');
        
        // create volume level indicator
        var volumeLevelEl = document.createElement('div');
        volumeLevelEl.setAttribute('id', 'volume-level-indicator');

        // add volume level indicator to volume level container
        volumeLevelContainerEl.appendChild(volumeLevelEl);
        
        // add volume level container to box
        volumeLevelBox.appendChild(volumeLevelContainerEl);
        
        // set volume level container to use for methods
        this.volumeLevelContainer = volumeLevelContainerEl;
        
        // set volume level indicator to use for methods
        this.volumeLevelIndicator = volumeLevelEl;

        // add box audio player
        this.audioPlayerContainer.appendChild(volumeLevelBox);

        // add event
        this.audioVolume.addEventListener('click', function() {

          self.muteAudio();

        }, false);

        // add event
        this.volumeLevelContainer.addEventListener('click', function() {

          self.setNewVolume(this,event);

        }, false);
  
      } else if (this.volumeIconInclude && !this.volumeBarInclude) {

        // create box
        var volumeIconBox = document.createElement('div');
        volumeIconBox.setAttribute('class', 'box-volumeicon');
        
        // create volume element
        var volumeIconContainerEl = document.createElement('div');
        volumeIconContainerEl.setAttribute('id', 'volume-icon-container');
        
        // create volume icon element
        var volumeIconEl = document.createElement('div');
        volumeIconEl.setAttribute('id', 'volume-icon');
        
        // create soundwave elements
        var volumeSoundwaveOne = document.createElement('span');
        volumeSoundwaveOne.innerHTML = ')';
        
        var volumeSoundwaveTwo = document.createElement('span');
        volumeSoundwaveTwo.innerHTML = ')';
        
        var volumeSoundwaveThree = document.createElement('span');
        volumeSoundwaveThree.innerHTML = ')';
        
        // add soundwaves to volume icon element
        volumeIconEl.appendChild(volumeSoundwaveOne);
        volumeIconEl.appendChild(volumeSoundwaveTwo);
        volumeIconEl.appendChild(volumeSoundwaveThree);
        
        // add volume-icon to volume icon container
        volumeIconContainerEl.appendChild(volumeIconEl);
        
        // add volume icon container to box
        volumeIconBox.appendChild(volumeIconContainerEl);
        
        // set element to use for volume icon
        this.audioVolume = volumeIconContainerEl;

        // add box audio player
        this.audioPlayerContainer.appendChild(volumeIconBox);

        // add event
        this.audioVolume.addEventListener('click', function() {

          self.muteAudio();

        }, false);

      } else if (!this.volumeIconInclude && this.volumeBarInclude) {

        // create box
        var volumeIconBox = document.createElement('div');
        volumeIconBox.setAttribute('class', 'box-volumeicon');

        // create volume level container
        var volumeLevelContainerEl = document.createElement('div');
        volumeLevelContainerEl.setAttribute('id', 'volume-level-container');
        
        // create volume level indicator
        var volumeLevelEl = document.createElement('div');
        volumeLevelEl.setAttribute('id', 'volume-level-indicator');

        // add volume level indicator to volume level container
        volumeLevelContainerEl.appendChild(volumeLevelEl);
        
        // add volume level container to box
        volumeIconBox.appendChild(volumeLevelContainerEl);
        
        // set volume level container to use for methods
        this.volumeLevelContainer = volumeLevelContainerEl;
        
        // set volume level indicator to use for methods
        this.volumeLevelIndicator = volumeLevelEl;

        // add box audio player
        this.audioPlayerContainer.appendChild(volumeIconBox);

        // add event
        this.volumeLevelContainer.addEventListener('click', function() {

          self.setNewVolume(this,event);

        }, false);

      }
  }
  

  // METHODS
  
  // display audio duration
  this.displayAudioDuration = function () {

    if (this.audioFileEndInclude) {
    
      this.audioFileEnd.innerHTML = Math.floor(this.audioFile.duration / 60) + ":" + (Math.floor(this.audioFile.duration % 60) < 10 ? '0' : '') + Math.floor(this.audioFile.duration % 60);
    
    }

  },
  
  // display current time of audio
  this.updateTime = function () {

    var currentSeconds = (Math.floor(this.audioFile.currentTime % 60) < 10 ? '0' : '') + Math.floor(this.audioFile.currentTime % 60);
    
    var currentMinutes = Math.floor(this.audioFile.currentTime / 60);

    if (this.audioFileStartInclude) {

      this.audioFileStart.innerHTML = currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds;

    }
    
    if (this.progressBarInclude) {

      var audioPlayedPercent = (this.audioFile.currentTime/this.audioFile.duration);

      var audioProgressPercent = this.audioProgressContainer.offsetWidth * audioPlayedPercent;
    
      this.audioProgressBar.style.width = Math.round(audioProgressPercent) + "px";
    
    }

    if (this.audioFile.currentTime == this.audioFile.duration) {

        if (this.playPauseBtnInclude) {
        
          this.playPauseBtn.innerHTML = "&#x25b6;";

          this.playPauseBtn.setAttribute("class", "");

        }
    };
    
  },

  // play / pause audio
  this.playPauseAudio = function () {
    
    if (this.audioFile.paused) {

        this.audioFile.play();

        this.playPauseBtn.innerHTML = "| |";
        
        this.playPauseBtn.setAttribute("class", "playing");

    } else {

        this.audioFile.pause();

        this.playPauseBtn.innerHTML = "&#x25b6;";

        this.playPauseBtn.setAttribute("class", "");
    }
     
  },
    
  // compute current audio time in %
  this.setAudioLocation = function(percentage) {
    
    this.audioFile.currentTime = this.audioFile.duration * percentage;
    
  },

  // display current audio progress
  this.setAudioPosition = function (element, e) {
      
     var audioProgressContainerWidth = element.offsetWidth;

     var eventObject = window.event ? event : e;
     
     var clickLocation = eventObject.layerX;

     var percentage = (clickLocation/audioProgressContainerWidth);

     this.setAudioLocation(percentage);
    
  },

  // compute volume % and update ui
  this.setVolume = function (percentage) {
    
    this.audioFile.volume = percentage;

    if (this.volumeIconInclude) {

      if(percentage > 0.6) {

          // display 3 soundwaves
          this.audioVolume.innerHTML = '<div id="volume-icon"><span>)</span><span>)</span><span>)</span></div>';

          // remove class attributes (remove "muted" class)
          this.audioVolume.setAttribute("class", "");

      } else if(percentage > 0 && percentage <= 0.3) {
    
         this.audioVolume.innerHTML = '<div id="volume-icon"><span>)</span></div>';

          // remove class attributes (remove "muted" class)
         this.audioVolume.setAttribute("class", "");
        
      } else if(percentage == 0) {

          // "muted" class is target by css to update ui
          this.audioVolume.setAttribute("class", "muted");

      } else {

          // display 2 soundwaves
          this.audioVolume.innerHTML = '<div id="volume-icon"><span>)</span><span>)</span></div>';

          // remove class attributes (remove "muted" class)
          this.audioVolume.setAttribute("class", "");
      }

    }

    if (this.volumeBarInclude) {
      
      var percentofVolumeLevelContainer = this.audioFile.volume / 1;

      var percentofVolumeLevelIndicator = this.volumeLevelContainer.offsetWidth * percentofVolumeLevelContainer;

      this.volumeLevelIndicator.style.width = Math.round(percentofVolumeLevelIndicator) + "px";

    }

  },
  
  // set volume based on user click on volume bar
  this.setNewVolume = function (element, e) {
    
    var volumeLevelContainer = element.offsetWidth;

    var eventObject = window.event? event: e;

    var clickLocation = eventObject.layerX;

    var percentage = (clickLocation/volumeLevelContainer);

    this.setVolume(percentage);
    
  },

  // stop audio and update ui
  this.stopAudio = function () {
    
    this.audioFile.currentTime = 0;

    this.audioFile.pause();

    if (this.playPauseBtnInclude) {
    
      this.playPauseBtn.innerHTML = "&#x25b6;";
    
      this.playPauseBtn.setAttribute("class", "");

    }
    
  },

  // toggle muted audio
  this.muteAudio = function () {
    
    var isMuted = this.audioVolume.getAttribute("class") == "muted" ? true : false;

    var currentVolume = this.audioVolume.getAttribute("muteVolume");

    if(isMuted == true) {

        this.setVolume(currentVolume);

        this.audioVolume.setAttribute("class", "");

    } else {

      if (this.volumeBarInclude) {

        var previousVolume = this.volumeLevelIndicator.offsetWidth / this.volumeLevelContainer.offsetWidth;

      }

      this.setVolume(0);
    
      this.audioVolume.setAttribute("class", "muted");

      if (this.volumeBarInclude) {
    
        this.audioVolume.setAttribute("muteVolume", previousVolume);

      } else {

        this.audioVolume.setAttribute("muteVolume", 1);

      }
    }
  }
  
  // set max-width based on chosen included elements
  
  var audioPlayerMaxWidth = 0;
  
      if (this.playPauseBtnInclude) {
        
        audioPlayerMaxWidth += 34;
      }
  
      if (this.stopBtnInclude) {
        
        audioPlayerMaxWidth += 34;
      }
  
      if (this.audioFileStartInclude) {
        
          audioPlayerMaxWidth += 46;
      }
  
      if (this.progressBarInclude) {
        
        audioPlayerMaxWidth += 170;
      }
  
       if (this.audioFileEndInclude) {
         
        audioPlayerMaxWidth += 46;
      }
  
      if (this.volumeIconInclude) {
        
        audioPlayerMaxWidth += 46;
      }
  
      if (this.volumeBarInclude) {
        
        audioPlayerMaxWidth += 100;
      }
  
  var pixelMaxWidth = audioPlayerMaxWidth + 'px';

  this.audioPlayerContainer.style.maxWidth = pixelMaxWidth;

} 

// Create instance
var myAudioPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
```

```css
#audio-player {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #fdfdfd), color-stop(1, #e7e7e7));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #fdfdfd 0%, #e7e7e7 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #fdfdfd 0%, #e7e7e7 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #fdfdfd 0%, #e7e7e7 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #fdfdfd 0%, #e7e7e7 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fdfdfd 0%, #e7e7e7 100%);
}
#audio-player [class*=box-] {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#audio-player [class*=box-]:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #audio-player [class*=box-] {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    border: none;
  }
}
#audio-player .box-playpause {
  width: 12%;
  max-width: 34px;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #audio-player .box-playpause {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
#audio-player #play-pause-btn {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  color: #252525;
  cursor: pointer;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #audio-player #play-pause-btn {
    width: auto;
  }
}
#audio-player #play-pause-btn.playing {
  font-size: 16px;
}
#audio-player .box-stopbtn {
  width: 12%;
  max-width: 34px;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #audio-player .box-stopbtn {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
#audio-player #stop-btn {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background-color: #252525;
  cursor: pointer;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #audio-player #stop-btn {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
#audio-player .box-audiofilestart {
  width: 16%;
  max-width: 46px;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #audio-player .box-audiofilestart {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
#audio-player #audio-file-start {
  color: #252525;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#audio-player .box-progressbar {
  width: 36%;
  max-width: 170px;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #audio-player .box-progressbar {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
#audio-player #audio-progress-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12px;
  background: #626262;
  border: 1px solid #818181;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#audio-player #audio-progress-bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 0;
  height: 12px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, #fff, #fff 5px, #dedede 5px, #dedede 10px);
  border-radius: 6px;
}
#audio-player .box-audiofileend {
  width: 16%;
  max-width: 46px;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #audio-player .box-audiofileend {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
#audio-player #audio-file-end {
  color: #252525;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#audio-player .box-volumeicon {
  width: 16%;
  max-width: 46px;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #audio-player .box-volumeicon {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
#audio-player #volume-icon-container {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 16px;
}
#audio-player #volume-icon {
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background: #252525;
  border-radius: 1px 0 0 1px;
  margin-right: 16px;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #audio-player #volume-icon {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
#audio-player #volume-icon:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -6px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid #252525;
}
#audio-player #volume-icon-container span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 12px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #252525;
}
#audio-player #volume-icon-container span:nth-child(2) {
  left: 16px;
}
#audio-player #volume-icon-container span:nth-child(3) {
  left: 20px;
}
#audio-player #volume-icon-container.muted span {
  visibility: hidden;
}
#audio-player .box-volumelevel {
  width: 20%;
  max-width: 100px;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #audio-player .box-volumelevel {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
#audio-player #volume-level-container {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #818181;
}
#audio-player #volume-level-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, #fff, #fff 5px, #dedede 5px, #dedede 10px);
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<audio id="audio-file"></audio>
<div id="audio-player"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Самая простая реализация это тег audio (http://htmlbook.ru/html/audio), нужно будет только звук поконверитить в разные форматы, чтобы во всех браузерах воспроизводилось